# Creating dictionary from list of tuples giving only subset of key-value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples of data and a `datetime` object.

`..[(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 3, 22, 36), 43.988269794721404), (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 3, 22, 36), 43.988269794721404), (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 3, 22, 36), 43.988269794721404), (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 3, 22, 36),..`

I am trying to create a dictionary from this list of tuples. So I call 
`d = dict(tuple_list)`

BUT, the output is simply the last element in the list , `{datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 3, 3, 22, 36): 43.988269794721404}`.

What is going on here? I am using python 2.7. I also tried 
`new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}` but that didn't work either! Thanks for the help!

Comment: How many unique keys do you have?

Comment: if the unique keys again occurring in dictionary, then it will override the latest value to that key

Comment: Please provide a code example that shows the problem you are having, instead of just describing the problem.

Comment: Upon further review I realize that my date parser was wrong and I have only 1 unique key....I feel very dumb haha. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all NO [python 2.7](https://pythonclock.org/)

Your getting the last element because you list of tuples all have the same first value.

A dict MUST have unique keys.

Comment: Thanks! Just realized that. I feel quite silly right now.

Comment: If that satisfies you please accept so this question can be closed